# Java Application Restart or Reset Button

Tags: java, button, jlabel, reset, restart

I have a very simple, choose your path, Java game that I am working on in the NetBeans IDE. Basically what happens is the user will click one of the three buttons, and pre-made `JLabel`'s which are set to `""` (nothing) will be reset to whatever text I decide that label should then use. I do this by adding the code below.

```
private void option1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    jLabel6.setText("You go down the dark tunnel...");
}
```

Now all this works fine but I'd like a way to restart/reset my application by clicking a button labelled "restart". I don't mind if it has to close the application and then open it again or if it will simply reset all the JLabel's back to "". I just don't want to have to type out the code below for every single JLabel.

```
jLabel1.setText("");
jLabel2.setText("");
jLabel3.setText("");
```

I have done some research on this site and none of the code that people provide seems to work for my situation, either because it simply doesn't work or because I am doing something wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated and please try and be specific because I am fairly new to writing Java and don't understand everything.

It would also work for me if someone could provide a way for me to close 1 window in an application instead of the whole thing, like when

```
System.exit(0);
```

is used.

Comment: It is not clear really what your problem is

Comment: There isn't enough code nor enough of an explanation of the problem here to provide any sort of answer that isn't guesswork.

Comment: @Thusitha Thilina Dayaratne I would like to restart my program, so at any part of the game that the user is at, when the restart button is clicked, the game will return to its beginning state that it was at when the application was first run.

Comment: If you having this game as .jar file then you can use
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar urapp.jar");
System.exit(0);

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#dispose()

Comment: If you decide to answer yourself please post it as an answer and accept it (it's legitimate to answer your own question).

Comment: @user1803551 will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question:

Thanks to Holger for suggesting "dispose". This is what I found worked.

```
private void restartButtonActionPerformed(ActionEvent evt)  {
    if(evt.getSource() == restartButton)
    {
        dispose();
        MyGUI game = new MyGUI();
        game.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

First, I recommend importing the JLabel class specifically so you can write `JLabel` instead of `javax.swing.JLabel`:

```
import javax.swing.JLabel;
```

Instead of declaring each JLabel individually, create an Array of JLabels:

```
JLabel[] jLabels = new JLabel[N]; // where N is the number of JLabels
```

Whenever you need to access a JLabel, use:

```
jLabels[6].setText("You go down the dark tunnel...");
```

When you want to reset all the JLabels, use:

```
for (JLabel jLabel : jLabels) {
    jLabel.setText("");
}
```

For more details on Arrays, read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: He is using fully qualified names because the GUI builder did if for him.

Comment: @user1803551 yeah you're right but just after the question I decided to get rid of the generator so I have more control.

Answer (score 0):

If you are having your program as a executable jar file then you can use

```
public void restert(){
     Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar yourapp.jar");
     System.exit(0);
}
```

If you want to know more about restarting java application you can go through [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/programmatically-restart-java)